# Perl modules for web automation

Tags: perl

My situation: Want to create a perl script to automate web login page. I need also to be able to pass in (POST) components such as HTTP Headers, i.e X-forwarded-for, username, password, csrf tokens and the likes. I know of Mechanize, but which other modules can I use to do the mentioned? Can LWP do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Library recommendations are off-topic, so I'll focus the question about LWP.

Yes, LWP::UserAgent (and its subclass WWW::Mechanize) can be used to send arbitrary headers.

`$ua->request` takes a request object with custom headers. You can create this object and perform the request as follows:

```perl
use HTTP::Request::Common qw( GET );

my $request = GET($url, 
   HeaderName => 'HeaderValue',
   HeaderName => 'HeaderValue',
);

my $response = $ua->request($request);
```

LWP:UserAgent provides a shorthand for this.

```perl
my $response = $ua->get($url,
   HeaderName => 'HeaderValue',
   HeaderName => 'HeaderValue',
);
```